# Element loses sticky behavior on switching to RTL

Tags: html, css, sticky, right-to-left

I need to place a pseudo-element `::after` inside the scrollable container in a non-scrollable way.

I achieved this **only** with `position: sticky` *(as `position:absolute` is scrollable)*.

**BUT** on switching `direction` to RTL:

> **Chromium**: the element fully misplaced  [ISSUE](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1353348)
> *(Please vote for the issue)*

> **Safari**: the element placed right, but not `sticky`

> **Firefox**: no bugs, works as it should ✅

```css
.example {
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow-x: overlay; 
  overflow-y: hidden; 
}

.example div {
  min-width: 1000px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.rtl ~ .example {
  direction: rtl;
}

.example::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: sticky;
  outline: 20px solid lightcoral;
  inset-inline-start: 0;
  inset-inline-end: 100%;
  bottom: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="this.classList.toggle('rtl')">TOGGLE RTL</button>
<br>
<br>
<div class="example">
  <div>Some long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long  text here</div>
</div>
```

### How it should work

[image: How it should work]

Comment: Why use `outline`? Give some `width` and `height` then use `background` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`position: sticky` has a good few limitations, one of which is ltr compatibility.

as far as i can see, you don't actually need `sticky` behaviour though, so what i'd suggest is have another parent container around your ltr-able element, and move your non-scrollable `after` element into this and use `position: absolute;`:

```css
.example {
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow-x: overlay; 
  overflow-y: hidden; 
}

.example div {
  min-width: 1000px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.rtl ~ .example-wrap .example {
  direction: rtl;
}

.example-wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.example-wrap::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  position: absolute;
  
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="this.classList.toggle('rtl')">TOGGLE RTL</button>
<br>
<br>
<div class="example-wrap">
  <div class="example">
    <div>Some long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long  text here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's an interesting issue, and indeed, `sticky` is often a bit buggy. But I also noticed the `rtl` setting breaks the scrollbar. At least in Safari.